# Select2 - infinite scroll not loading next page with remote data

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2-4

I am using `Select2 4.0.1`, I have used ajax to populate the result based on users input, but whenever I search for anything `select2` lists first page result, but consecutive pages were not loading, also request is made for 2nd page on scroll. seems to be I am missing something.

```
$multiselect = $(element).select2({
    closeOnSelect: false,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: 'Assign a new tag',
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [","],
    ajax: {
      url: '/search_url',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          search: params.term,
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        var more, new_data;
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        more = {
          more: (params.page * 20) < data.total_count
        };
        new_data = [];
        data.items.forEach(function(i, item) {
          new_data.push({
            id: i.name,
            text: i.name
          });
        });
        return {
          pagination: more,
          results: new_data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  })
```

Any help is much appreciated.Thnx:)

Comment: Is anything appearing in your console? Try initializing Select2 with `debug: true` to see if any warnings show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the code I got working last week. I am using a different transport on my end, but that shouldn't make a difference. I was having the same issue as you regarding the lack of paging working while scrolling. My issue ended up being that I didn't have the proper `{'pagination':{'more':true}}` format in my `processResults` function.  The only thing I can see that may work for you is to "fix" the page count in the `data` function vs. the `processResults` function.

When you scroll to the bottom of your list, do you see the "Loading more results..." label?  Have you attempted to hard code the `more` value to `true` while debugging?

```
        this.$(".select2").select2({
            'ajax': {
                'transport': function (params, success, failure) {
                    var page = (params.data && params.data.page) || 1;
                    app.do('entity:list:search',{'types':['locations'],'branch':branch,'limit':100,'page':page,'term':params.data.term})
                    .done(function(locations) {
                        success({'results':locations,'more':(locations.length>=100)});
                    });
                }
              , 'delay': 250
              , 'data':function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        'term': params.term
                      , 'page': params.page || 1
                    };

                    return query;
                }
              , 'processResults': function (data) {
                    return {
                        'results': data.results
                      , 'pagination': {
                            'more': data.more
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
          , 'templateResult': that.formatResult
          , 'templateSelection': that.formatSelection
          , 'escapeMarkup': function(m) { return m; }
        });
```